# Unity не отображает все поля в вкладке интерфейса

Tags: unity3d, интерфейс

Добрый день есть такая проблема. Как видно из скрина в Unity в инспекторе не отображаются некоторые поля она просто заштрихованы но активны то есть вписать в них что ли бо можно но ничего не видно. Такая проблема в основном в полях которые относятся к скрипту но иногда появляются и в других. Железо слабое наверное. Стоит карта 660gtx на 2 гб

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас слабый компьютер, то это скорей привело бы к тому что все медллено обновлялось в интерфейсе, а не вот такое вот...

Я бы предположил что у вас используются в проекте 'PropertyDrawer' какие-то свои, но у вас и стандартные свойства для капсюля отображаются также. Может попробовать переустановить unity?